# Adding an image for each element of a dropdown list in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a dropdown menu in Bootstrap in HTML. All I want to do is adding an image for each one of the elements of the dropdown list.
But when I try to execute it nothing happens. The dropdown list is ok but the images dont appear. Can someone help to add the images in a dropdown menu? Thanks!

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  Lingua &nbsp &nbsp
  <button class=" btn btn-default " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Italiano
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/flag.png" width="35" height="30">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/account.png" width="35" height="30">2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  &nbsp &nbsp Paese &nbsp &nbsp</tab>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Italia
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my result:
[image]
I'm sorry for the paint but I have to remove that button.

Comment: Are the images sourced correctly?

Comment: Please do update your code properly...

Answer (score 0):

Yoc Can Use This Code In Your Css File

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('Some.gif');
   }
```